# R: reshape() confuses data if columns aren't in order; bug?

Tags: r, reshape

When reshaping from wide to long format, the reshape() function in R mixes values if the variables aren't in correct order. An example:

```
df <- data.frame(Id=c(1,2),
             x.2000 = c(15,13),x.2001=c(21,61),x.2002=c(37,11),
             y.2002=c(14,58),y.2000=c(20,18),y.2001=c(9,73))
```

which produces

```
  Id x.2000 x.2001 x.2002 y.2002 y.2000 y.2001
1  1     15     21     37     14     20      9
2  2     13     61     11     58     18     73
```

Notice that the `y` variable isn't in correct chronological order. Applying reshape(), ordering by ID and renaming the rows with

```
df.long <- reshape(df,idvar = "Id", 
               timevar = "year", 
               times=seq(2000,2002),
               varying=names(df)[-1],
               direction="long")
df.long <- df.long[order(df.long[,"Id"]),]
rownames(df.long) <- 1:nrow(df.long)
```

gives

```
Id year  x  y
1  1 2000 15 14
2  1 2001 21 20
3  1 2002 37  9
4  2 2000 13 58
5  2 2001 61 18
6  2 2002 11 73
```

With no warning, R wrote the 2002 value of `y` in 2000, the 2000 value in 2001 and so on. Is there a way to correct this mistake?

Comment: I think the relevant part of the help text is "Notice that the order of variables in `varying` is like `x.1,y.1,x.2,y.2`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to `order` the dataset in the correct order based on the 'year'

```
i1 <- c(1 , 1+ order(as.numeric(sub(".*\\.", "", names(df)[-1]))))
df <- df[i1]
```

`reshape`ing with the OP's code on the dataset gives

```
df.long
#  Id year  x  y
#1  1 2000 15 20
#2  1 2001 21  9
#3  1 2002 37 14
#4  2 2000 13 18
#5  2 2001 61 73
#6  2 2002 11 58
```

---

or instead of ordering the columns of data, change the order in the `varying`

```
i2 <- match(sub(".*\\.", "", names(df)[-1]), 2000:2002)
reshape(df, idvar = "Id", timevar = "year", times = 2000:2002, 
       varying = names(df)[-1][order(i2)], direction = "long")
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. But shouldn't this be considered a bug in the reshape() function?

Comment: @Durden  I think you are not trying to match the sequence with the names.  Instead, it is given a sequence and the function assumes the columns in that sequence order